# is there a way to rewrite part of a URL using htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

i ran into a problem with wordpress when it comes to displaying weekly posts using wp_get_archives. what i need is to display a weekly archive for a specific category but wordpress only allows that for monthly and yearly archiving, not weekly. i came up with an idea to just display the URLs and then rewrite the URLs using htaccess but am wondering how I could go about changing just part of the URL. for instance, change

http://www.domain.com/2012?w=29

to

http://www.domain.com/category/name?w=20?m=2012

what I need is to keep the ?w=29 and insert 'http://www.domain.com/category/name' before it and ?m=2012 after whenever the URL contains 2012?w=

this is the only part of the site that is displaying archives in this way so it's not going to break anything else on the site which is why i want to take this approach.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule /^(.*)\?w\=(.*)$                    /category/name?w=$1&m=$2
```

Comment: i added this rule to my .htaccess file but it's not properly redirecting: 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#
RewriteRule ^category/weightlifting\?w\=([^/]*)\?m\=2012$ /2012?w=$1 [L]
#
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress
</IfModule>'